# Tabnine autocomplete AI stopped working in Visual Studio and tells me to go on Tabnine Hub

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I installed Tabnine autocomplete not long ago (around 2 hours) in visual studio via the Extensions (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>). I turned off my visual studio environment or I closed the IDE for a while. and now I can't use Tabnine...

I have tried to click on the little logo in the status bar which says `(Click to open settings)`. But nothing seems to work. It had worked the first time I used Tabnine on python, but now for some reason it has stopped working on any language I use it on...

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall it or install the older version?

Comment: @Steven-MSFT I have, but it seems to have not worked for me

Comment: Sorry for being late, could you disable all the extensions and then enable the needed extensions to have a test?

Comment: @Steven-MSFT I have turned off everything except; Python.Pylance and Tabnine yet nothing has changed for me...

Answer (score 2):

I also have this problem, they have release the update in the Discord Server. You should join [this server](https://discord.gg/hKb2QYrBtm) and ask for help.

**This is what I have done to fix it(it might not works for you)**

1. Uninstall the extension.
2. Go to `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage`
3. Delete `tabnine.tabnine-vscode` folder
4. Install the extension again.
   That's all I could help, if this doesn't work, join [Discord Server](https://discord.gg/hKb2QYrBtm) and ask the staff there.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it seems to have not worked for me

Comment: Oh, I forgot to tell you, they have release a bux fix update in their Discord Server.